# When a value changes it then is transfered to another sheet but also retains each change

Tags: excel, vba

So if N11 from sheet1 changes then it's posted to A2 in sheet2 but then next input from N11 would go to A3 and so on. I tried this code, I'm not to familiar with VBA and just trying out new things in excel for a personal project. This code was pulled from another forum that someone tried to help me with but haven't heard back yet. I'm using a formula in N11 and trying to get that number pasted to Sheet2 to A3 once that value changes, so I can record a range of data and make a chart from that.

[Found from other forum I think it worked cause he said if it's a formula it might works with this Worksheet_calculate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZEd.png)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Me.Range("N11").Address Then    
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")    
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1).Value = Target.Value    
        End With    
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks good. What is it that it doesn't do?

Comment: So when the data changes in N11 it doesn't do anything to my sheet2 where A column is. N11 is currently a formula adding up the sum of the numbers above it and those numbers change depending on my stock data if that helps.

Comment: The code must be in the code sheet of the tab on which you have Cell N11. That location is vital. Any other location (such as `Module1`) and the code won't ever be called.

Comment: If the cell is changing due to a formula then the worksheet_change event won't catch the change.  You need to use the _Calculate event.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working, did you make sure you placed the subroutine in the sheet's macro module? See image.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim lRow As Long
   MsgBox ("Hello")
   If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B2" Then
      lCol = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, lCol + 1).Value = Target.Value
   End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I did that part and pasted it under Sheet1 where your arrow is and saved as it as a .xlsm. I even changed a variable in my table to have N11 change and I looked at Sheet2 and the table didn't update.

Comment: can you get a simple message box to appear when you change the value in the sheet? trying to figure out if your subroutine is even getting called at all.

Comment: So when I type a random number in N11 manually over the formula, I get this error. "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. When I click debug it goes to the line with "With Worksheets ("sheet2")" highlighting it with yellow.

Comment: Ah sorry about that one didn't see it, also one more mistake on my side, I created this sheet after my second one but moved it to be in between so it was technically sheet 3 but I changed the variables around and still no change though. I did see the msg hello after every change I did.

Comment: Not yet I still see no change to sheet3. On sheet3 I got my table with titles there and A2 where would the first number be going but yeah that's just still blank everytime I change some number that changes N11.

Comment: So in that other forum the guy came back and had me try this, initially something didn't work but it works now had to something on the table as well. I provided a IMG in my initial post at top, of the code I used.